# how to connect elastix-asterisk to remote database?

Tags: php, asterisk, elastix

I have been working on elastix on a local setup ,and I have copied the database to remote server , now I am struggling to configure elastix and a2billing to that remote database , I have changed the following files but still not connecting to the remote database :

```
./asterisk/cdr_mysql.conf --> to change for cdr tables
./asterisk/cbmysql.conf --> to change for meetme app
./asterisk/res_mysql.conf --> to change a2billing realtime
./a2billing.conf  --> to change main a2billing database
```

appreciate the help if something is missing

Regards,

Comment: You should provide more details on which database are you using and make sure you verify with db client that elastix server can actually reach remote database with reference to TCP/IP and firewall settings as well as database internal security.

Comment: @hlihovac I am using mysql that was included with Elastix iso , but I have to connect to other mysql database to sync two servers , and so for the firewall and privileges everything is ok

Comment: Could you provide contents of mentioned config files and if anything relevant available logs?

Comment: @hlihovac , content just replace localhost or 127.0.0.1 , with server IP for the hosted database , as for the logs [ not much of logs ] , just when you try to login into a2billing [connection failed appear ]

Comment: then next thing I would recommend to verify is security on mysql server for given user (if it is allowed to connect) accessing from exlastix server.  
  
    `echo 'select Host, User  from user;' |  mysql -t -uroot -p mysql`

Comment: @hlihovac , I have granted %@% with grant option

Answer (score 0):

With the "struggling" word is hard to tell wich is your error or problem. Most common problems is security from MySQL refusing to connect remote IP Addresses. Also is the confusing that Elastix use Sqlite3 databases (stored in /var/www/db) and Asterisk use MySQL, but the Call details record is in MySQL asteriskcdrdb, so I am thinking is this your target:

1. Open and Edit "etc/my.cnf" using vi or any editor.
2. Add "skip-grant-tables" under [mysqld]. Save changes.
3. Restart MySql to take the changes using "service mysqld start".